# Mac OS X Yosemite automatic logon

Tags: mac, osx-yosemite, auto-login

I want to configure Max OS X Yosemite with automatic logon.

I checked tutorials, but the option to activate it, even with superuser, is blocked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you unlock the Control Panel first?

Once Unlocked you should be able to set the drop menu in Login Options to whichever user you prefer…

[image]